# How to confine an animated div to its parent div

Tags: javascript, css, animation, html

I have an animated div placed inside a div, I only want this div to be able to move in the space of it's parent. How would I go about doing that?

Simply: I want frog contained within frogger.

**HTML**

```
<div id="frogger">                          <!-- Animate start -->
  <button id="left">&laquo;</button> <button id="right">&raquo;</button>
    <div id="frog">
    </div>
</div>                                      <!-- Animate end -->
```

**CSS**

```
#frogger
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#frog
{
  position:relative;
  background-color:#abc;
  left:50px;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#right").click(function(){
    if ($(':animated').length) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#frog").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, {queue: false}, "slow");
    }   
});

$("#left").click(function(){
    if ($(':animated').length) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#frog").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, {queue: false}, "slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: @nnnnnn I may have to do that, I just thought there would be a simpler solution, such as making it's parent div the boundaries.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment to post it as an answer before I saw that you'd replied to it. I don't think there is any way to have your frog element be automatically constrained by its parent's dimensions, because CSS relative and absolute positioning quite deliberately allows you to move the child past the edges of the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to test the current position and not move if it is too close to the edge:

```
var $frog = $("#frog");

$("#right").click(function(){
    if (parseInt($frog.css('left')) >= 400 || $(':animated').length) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $frog.animate({"left": "+=50px"}, {queue: false}, "slow");
    }   
});

$("#left").click(function(){

    if (parseInt($frog.css('left')) < 50 || $(':animated').length) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $frog.animate({"left": "-=50px"}, {queue: false}, "slow");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n3NgY/

Of course you can make this a bit more robust by determining the width of the frog and its container programmatically, but for the purpose of a quick demo I've just hardcoded the appropriate left and right boundary numbers.

Comment: Works just the way I wanted, thanks.

The only thing that worries me is that if I change the dimensions of the parent div then it seems like I'd have to modify this js too, which is why I was hoping there was a solution where you could just confine a child to its parent.

But this works too, thanks again.

Comment: Well like I said in my last paragraph, I only hardcoded the values for demo purposes. In your final implementation you'd calculate the numbers based on the current width of the frog and parent (or if the widths don't change dynamically you'd store the widths in variables on document ready, but either way you wouldn't hardcode them). Although you don't need the width of either element to test whether to move left since you know the left boundary is 0.

Comment: Yeh sorry about that, commented before I realized you commented >.<
Your solution is actually working beautifully, and yeh I shouldn't have to hardcode any changes in if I code this right, sorry, I'm new.
Thanks again.

Comment: [If you're curious here's my finished result](http://jsfiddle.net/n3NgY/1/), you're right I won't have to hardcode it! :D
It's also controlled by arrow keys now.
Again, thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you'll need to do a bit of simple collision detection, unfortunately CSS alone won't allow you to do this. But you can do it dynamically like so:

```
$("#right").click(function(){
    var frog_right = $("#frog").offset().left + $("#frog").width();
    var frogger_right = $("#frogger").offset().left + $("#frogger").width();

    if ($(':animated').length || frog_right >= frogger_right ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#frog").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, {queue: false}, "slow");
    }   
});

$("#left").click(function(){
    var frog_left = $("#frog").offset().left;
    var frogger_left = $("#frogger").offset().left;

    if ($(':animated').length || frog_left <= frogger_left) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#frog").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, {queue: false}, "slow");
    }
});
```